# Changing the background color of the movie while using tpad and adelay

Tags: ffmpeg

i want to change the background color of a movie while using `tpad` and `adelay` commands. it is now black ( until the movie starts).

the command i tried listed below, and i don't know how to change the color while the movie is in it's delay ( probably something with the `tpad` that needs to be change).

```
 -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1920:1080,tpad=start_duration=5[v];
  [0:a]adelay=5s|s[a] -map [v] -map [a] -b 6000k
```

the 5 seconds that the movie is in its `"waiting mode"` needs to be changed from default black to some other color. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the color option for tpad.

`tpad=start_duration=5:color=blue`.